# Passing objects to Detail View with filter (Django)

Tags: django, filtering, detailview

I am trying to pass query of comments (Comment model) to a DetailView of Post model using filter to get in DetailView only comments, related to particlural post.

Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=500, help_text='Не более 500 знаков')
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_id = models.ForeignKey(on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Detail veiw:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'post'
    model = Post

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comments'] = Comment.objects.filter(post_id = self.model.id)
        return context
```

And it returns TypeError:

```
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'DeferredAttribute'
```

Could you please help with recommendation regarding how correctly use a filter to get in DetailView only comments, related to this Post? Thanks!

Comment: `self.model` is `Post`, *not* a `Post` object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well here your `self.model` will return `Post` (a reference to the model class), not the post object.

You can access the object with `self.object`, as is specified in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview):

> While this view is executing, **`self.object` will contain the object** that the view is operating upon.

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'post'
    model = Post

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comments'] = Comment.objects.filter(post_id=self.object)
        return context
```

You can also make use of the reversed relationship, like:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'post'
    model = Post

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comments'] = self.object.comment_set.all()
        return context
```

> **Note**: note that a `ForeignKey` field typically does *not* end with an `_id` suffix, Django will automatically add an extra field named `fieldname_id`, so here you have two fields, `post_id`, and `post_id_id`, which is quite strange.

Comment: Understood. Thanks!